Fixing Dimension Errors During Training of Simple NN
I hope you're doing well.
I'm currently working on a project to convert speech to text using PyTorch. I've been able to implement this code using GPT, but I encounter an error during training and I can't resolve the issue.
I would appreciate it if you could review my code and point out the problem. Thank you.
The error is :
This is my colab link that contains code : https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1tC2nBpMjFLC-HTL3ZV57touKaAMAhSyJ?usp=sharing
